# Is there a better way to test if a char is whitespace than converting it to a string?

Tags: rust, char, slice

I have a function that checks if a `char` is whitespace:

```
fn is_any_whitespace(ch: &char) -> bool {
    let re = Regex::new(r"\s").unwrap();
    let slice = &ch.to_string()[..];
    re.is_match(slice)
}
```

What bothers me is the part where I convert `char` to `&str` (`&str` is the type of the parameter that `is_match` accepts):

```
&ch.to_string()[..]
```

Can it be done more elegantly and efficiently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using regex for this problem, you can use [`char::is_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace). It should have the same behavior and will likely be more efficient, depending on compiler optimizations. In any case, not depending on the `regex` crate is a gain.

The only real difference is that `char::is_whitespace` takes `self` rather than `&self`. If you're worried about that, don't be. Using `&char` over `char` has no gain since `char` implements `Copy`. In fact, since `char`s are 4 bytes, it'll typically be *more* efficient to pass the characters directly, rather than an 8 byte pointer. And that's not even taking into account the extra layer of indirection.

If you insist on using the approach you have, it can be simplified to

```
use regex::Regex;

fn is_any_whitespace(ch: &char) -> bool {
    let re = Regex::new(r"\s").unwrap();
    re.is_match(&ch.to_string())
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b974814a860a853acdb9894bc2b3d1b)